# request.fullpath inconsistency between dev and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2

On my development machine with webrick, an incoming POST request from an external service such as

```
https://localhost:3000/projects?name=stuff&length=5
```

request.fullpath shows

```
/projects?name=stuff&length=5
```

On Heroku, request.fullpath shows

```
/projects
```

Does anyone know why?

**UPDATE**
I'm merely showing request.fullpath output using logger

```
ProjectsController.rb

def create
     Rails.logger.debug "\n\nfullpath=#{request.fullpath}\n\n"
...
end
```

If it makes any difference, I just remembered that the POST from the external service is HTTPS. I have configured the external service to POST using HTTP and still has the same issue.

In case anyone is curious, I check Heroku's version using the console

```
>> Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "3.0.9"
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.9.2"
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using `request.fullpath`.

Comment: Updated question in response to your question

Comment: Did you check you have exactly the same version on both environments?

Comment: I just checked, Heroku has the same version of Ruby and Rails as my dev setup stated above.

Comment: How do you know `/projects?name=stuff&length=5` is actually being hit

Comment: I see it in the logs, that's where I put the Rails.logger.debug statement, this is from Heroku's logs Started POST "/projects" for 66.211.170.66 at 2011-07-24 19:33:17 -0700. Plus I also dumped the query string showing params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `fullpath` should always return the query string--see [these tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/test/dispatch/request_test.rb#L217-245) in the Rails source code.

What does the form that performs the POST look like? Are you positive that there were no differences in your test on development and production?

Comment: See above, I verified that Heroku has the same version of Ruby and Rails as my dev setup. It's not a form that does the POST, this is coming from an external service and I assume they are doing a HTTPS call. I can see in my dev and prod logs that it is a POST. The format is as I stated above.

Comment: Is it possible that you're/they're/it's just POSTing to whatever URL they currently have, and that sometimes there are optional query string parameters (e.g. in dev) and sometimes there aren't (in prod)?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure they do not post without query string params, it's in their documentation plus I was able to dump out params on prod which clearly shows the url params being passed

Comment: You know what, I think you are right, at least more right than what I understood. While they are passing the params, they seem to be passing it in a form and not as part of the url params. This is counter to what their documentation said, argh. I'll have to check with them tomorrow.